# Tengo problemas al imprimir desde un servidor web con IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, iis

Tengo una aplicación web con ASP.NET MVC alojada en un servidor con IIS. Esta aplicación me debería imprimir un voucher o comprobante al momento de que el usuario haga clic sobre algún botón de acción.

Realice la prueba en mi ambiente de desarrollo (local), desde el visual studio para imprimir los voucher los cuales se imprimen bien. Todo esto con los respectivos driver de la impresora instalados en mi maquina. Y ahora acá viene el problema...

Pasa que hice deploy hacia mi servidor de pruebas de mi aplicacion web, pero al llamar a la url de mi aplicacion web desde un browser de un cliente (un pc) o de mi misma maquina cliente que si funcionaba la impresion cuando levantaba la aplicacion con el visual, ahora no imprime nada, de hecho se cae con un erro 500 de servidor.

Agregue un try para detectar cual es el error que me envia el servidor y el mensaje es `{"error":"No hay impresoras instaladas."} siendo que en mi maquina cliente si tengo isntalada la impresora y los drivers.

Para despejar dudas temrine instalando los driver de la impresora en el servidor pero tampoco funciono y sigue enviando el mismo mensaje de error.

¡Alguien sabe que sucede?

a todo esto estoy imprimiendo con C# usando PrintDocument`

Comment: Hola, en el momento en que has desplegado en un servidor IIS, las impresoras son las propias de dicho servidor. Verifica que ese equipo dispone de las impresoras correctamente configuradas

Comment: Es que el servidor no tiene ninguna impresora por que necesito que desde las maquinas cliente se impriman los voucher, solo las maquinas clientes tienen impresoras configuradas.

Comment: Recuerda que en el modelo cliente-servidor, el servidor provee a los clientes no al revés. Necesitas dar de alta mediante red todas la impresoras en el servidor.

Comment: Para que un cliente web pueda acceder a los recursos locales deberías implementar algo como un control ActiveX.

Comment: O también puedes generar lo que se denomina Vista de impresión de una página y habilitar un botón que ejecute el código JS `window.print()`